# Printing dashes with and array

Tags: java

I have to write a method called print() that prints out the results as follows;

```
Original:
-----------
|9|7|9|4|3|
-----------
Sorted:
-----------
|3|4|7|9|9|
-----------
```

My new code is as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i< intArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(i==intArray.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print("----\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("----");
            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i< intArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                System.out.println("| "+intArray[i]+" | ");
            }
            else if(i==intArray.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print(intArray[i]+" |\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(intArray[i]+" | ");
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i< intArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(i==intArray.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print("----\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("----");
            }

        }
```

Its almost perfect except one number is out of place and is displaying as follows:

### Original:

| 3 |

### 2 | 9 | 9 | 6 |

### Sorted:

| 2 |

### 3 | 6 | 9 | 9 |

Frequencies:

### Original:

| 9 |

### 1 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 8 | 5 | 8 | 5 | 1 |

### Sorted:

| 1 |

### 1 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 9 |

Frequencies:

Can somebody please tell me what the problem is as I can't figure it out. Thanks for all of your help in the comments

Comment: Just realised its not showing some of the dashes but there is supposed to be dashes above and below the numbers in the array like so -------

Comment: Do you know of the difference between `println` and `print`?

Comment: And what is it printing?

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` appends a newline after the output, that is, after every array item in your code. You should use `System.out.print` instead. Also it looks like you are only printing the pipes at the end of the array, making it look something like

```
34799|
```

For the example output you need something like

```
public void print()
{
    //no need for \n, println produces one at the end of the string
    System.out.println("-------------------"); 
    System.out.print("|");
    for(int i=0;i< intArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(intArray[i] + "|");
    }
    System.out.print("\n-------------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `if-else`, we can print the array with a simple for loop, e.g.:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println("--------------");
System.out.print("|");
for(int element : array){
    System.out.print(element + "|");
}
System.out.println("--------------");
```

**update**

Here's how it works:

- First `println()` prints first dashed line.
- Second `print()` before the `for loop` prints initial '|'
- `print()` in the `for loop` prints element appended by '|'
- There is no need to print the last '|' it is already done in the for loop.
- Last `println()` prints dashed line after the array contents.

Comment: The most important change being `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Good solution. It would be better if it addressed the OP's question about dashes above and below. Yes, I know you've solved it. Please explain it.

Comment: Done.. I have added the explanation :)

Comment: The question is about the dashes above and below. You've described the pipes in between. :-(